# Passport js local strategy using Postgresql not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js

Hi Im posting again in hope someone can help me ,here's my problem Im working with MVC architecture so i have 3 folders controller,model and view for now what im focusing on is server part ,i want to make this work but i have no idea what is wrong and what should i do please help.
in my model i have

```
 const findUserByEmail = (email) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {    
    console.log("jqhhbsd"),
      con.query(
          ' SELECT * FROM `personne_physique` WHERE `email` = $1  ', email,
          function(err, rows) {
              if (err) {
                  reject(err)
              }
              let user = rows[0];
              resolve(user);
          }
      );
  } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
 });
};

const comparePassword = (mot_de_passe, userObject) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
      await bcrypt.compare(mot_de_passe, userObject.mot_de_passe).then((isMatch) => {
          if (isMatch) {
              resolve(true);
          } else {
              resolve(`The password that you've entered is incorrect`);
          }
      });
  } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
     }
 });
};
```

This is my controller an i use these requires
const user= require("../models")

const passport=require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

```
  initializePassport : () => {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'mot_de_passe',
        passReqToCallback: true

    },
    
    async (req, email, mot_de_passe, done) => {
        try {
            await user.findUserByEmail(email).then(async (user) => {
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash("errors", `This user email "${email}" doesn't exist`));
                }
                if (user) {
                    let match = await user.comparePassword(mot_de_passe, user);
                    if (match === true) {
                        return done(null, user, null)
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash("errors", match)
                        )
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(null, false, { message: err });
        }
    }));

  }
```

Finally here's my routing

```
 router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
failureRedirect: '/users/login',

 }),
function(req, res) {
console.log('Authentication successful');
res.redirect('/login');
 });
```

Also i get this message running postman "message": "Unknown authentication strategy "local"".

Please if you have any idea how you can help me do share with me .

Comment: And are you definitely configuring `passport` _befofe_ you configure your routes? Because that's what the error is suggesting the problem is?

Comment: can u explain more please?

Comment: app.use("/", require("./routes/routes"));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); this is in my app.js

Comment: Where does `initializePassport` get called? Show that in your code...

Comment: i don't use actually im really lost idk how to do this

Comment: can u help me find a solution to make this work?

Comment: This your code, you _should_ know where things are called. But basically, you need to have the strategy registered before you setup the route...

Comment: i actually just added it because i can't just put passport.use immediatly in module.exports (i have othercontrollers create/update/delete user) but using passport.use isn't working so i added the variable initializePassport..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230148/discussion-between-narry-storan-and-james).